# Make a function that can only be called from inside a user gesture in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, gesture

In Google Chrome, if you try to enter fullscreen mode by entering the command in the console it will fail with this error message:

> Failed to execute 'requestFullscreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture.

It is not possible (as far as I know) to trick this by simulating a click event. It only works when triggered inside a real user action. Several other built-in functions have this behaviour as well.

Can I reproduce this behaviour in my own functions?

In other words, **can I create a function that will work when triggered by a real human making a user gesture, but not in any other situation?**

Comment: @JosiahDaniels Wtf this is not a duplicate. I am asking how to require a user gesture in my function and not how to enter fullscreen mode.

Comment: @JosiahDaniels I don't want to trick the browser into going fullscreen. I want my own custom method fooBar()  to be only callable BY A USER GESTURE.

Answer (score 2):

In Chrome you can use `Event.isTrusted` ([MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted)).

When a user makes a gesture, you will probably get an event passed to your handler. Here's an example with the click event:

```js
document.documentElement.onclick = function(event)
{
  alert(event.isTrusted ? "trusted" : "untrusted");  
};

// After 5 seconds perform an untrusted click
setTimeout(function() { document.documentElement.click() }, 5000);
```

When an event is trusted, it was generated by a user action, so you can execute your function.